# Can I use a shared_ptr everywhere I want to use a simple pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm rather inexperienced with pointers and I'm having trouble with the difference between a simple pointer and a `std::shared_ptr`. I want to use a `shared_ptr` so I don't have to be so careful about  deleting the object when nothing points to it.

I am having trouble with a library/header I'm using ([easylogging++](https://github.com/easylogging/easyloggingpp)). I don't think it is a problem with the external library, but with my use of pointers. The library has a function that returns a simple pointer to an object. I always convert the simple pointer to `shared_ptr` and that is where the trouble happens.

```
// Works fine---but I want a shared_ptr
Object* MyInstance(ReturnPointerToObject(...));   
// Compiles fine, but crashes during deallocation of the Object (Seg fault?)
std::shared_ptr<Object> MyInstance(ReturnPointerToObject(...));
```

My program crashes when things are being deallocated at the end of the program.

Questions:

1. Is converting a pointer to `shared_ptr` like this a good or a bad idea?
2. Is it a problem with the external library I'm using?
3. Do I simply not understand pointers and shared pointers?

Comment: There isn't a simple recipe book which you can follow mechanically and magically produce correct C++. You have to *read and understand* the APIs that you consume. Object ownership transfer at API boundaries is part of the documentation.

Comment: The "so I don't have to be so careful about deleting the object" is actually the root cause, since you then don't care what happens, when it happens or why it happens. Shared pointers aren't there to allow the programmer to be sloppy, but as a convenience tool when the lifetime and ownership might be transferred between systems. You still _have_ to know about the lifetimes and ownership of your objects as well as the 3rdparty ones.

Comment: As @KerrekSB already indicated: only use shared (or unique) pointers if the API tells you you're responsible for cleaning up after you used the object (and as long as it doesn't indicate in any way that this doesn't hold unconditionally (sorry for triple negation)). Another problem might be that the API tells you to use a *special* deletion function (like many C APIs); in this case the shared pointer can be given that deletion function, but I am not experienced with this situation, please read the shared_ptr documentation for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you construct a `shared_ptr` to an object (from anything other than an existing `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr` to that object) you are creating a new scheme to manage the object's lifespan. If something else already controls that object's lifespan, then this is an utterly broken thing to do. If, for example, `ReturnPointerToObject` returns a pointer to someone else's object, you have no right to control the object's lifespan, and thus creating a `shared_ptr` to it is broken behavior and will result in `delete` being called erroneously.

I would also just advise against using `shared_ptr` where you don't actually need a shared pointer. The C++ way is that you don't pay for what you don't use, and other mechanisms (such as `unique_ptr`) exist for cases where sharing aren't needed. You are, of course, right to adopt a policy of avoiding naked pointers wherever possible.

Comment: Given that "Premature optimization is the root of all evil", doesn't it make sense to use shared_ptr by default? It provides the convenience of a GC'd language. When using unique_ptr I have to call move explicitly in some cases to trigger move semantics, and I can't use unique_ptr's in a list initializer since it triggers a copy.

Comment: @KeyboardDrummer It's not about optimization, it's about semantic correctness. If only one thing is supposed to own an object, using a `unique_ptr` permits you to enforce this at compile time and understand when and where ownership is being transferred.

Comment: Yes, "If only one thing is supposed to own an object", unique_ptr is ideal. However, why would you suppose this? Given that I'm using some pointer, all I need to know is whether I'm one of the owners. I'm not really interested in whether I'm the sole owner or not, right? The main advantage of unique_ptr over shared_ptr to me still seems that, I'm assuming, that it's faster. Given your expertise @David Schwartz, please enlighten me if I'm incorrect.

Comment: @KeyboardDrummer It's not that it's faster, it's that *if* only one thing is supposed to own the object, you can enforce this at compile time. It's that transfers of ownership are explicit in the code, making the code more self-documenting. If you have an object that can be owned by more than one thing, then you wouldn't use `unique_ptr`, not because of performance, but because it would then have the wrong semantics.

Comment: This is really the same answer as your first one, and it relies on the same premise "if only one thing is supposed to own the object". I'm questioning why ever you would suppose this. Given your premise "if only one thing is supposed to own the object", I totally agree you should be using unique_ptr to enforce safety and provide documentation.

Comment: @KeyboardDrummer I don't understand what you're saying. Are you saying you don't think it's common to have dynamically allocated objects that are owned by only one thing at a time? Consider, for example, a polymorphic factory function. (You can't return by value in this case due to slicing.)

Comment: Thanks David for your patience with me. 

In the factory example, I think it would make sense to use a unique_ptr for the return value. However I'd do this for performance reasons. Since you can move a unique_ptr into a shared_ptr, but not the otherway around, returning a unique_ptr gives the caller the option to keep the object in a fast unique_ptr. Semantically however there is no difference. The caller doesn't care whether or not he's the sole owner of the new object. It's only because the unique_ptr option has a potential performance benefit that I'd prefer it.

Comment: @KeyboardDrummer It's not that the caller cares whether he's the sole owner of the object. It's that if we returned a `shared_ptr`, the calling code could easily wind up creating more than one owner accidentally whereas with `unique_ptr`, this would be detected at compile time unless the calling code explicitly did something to permit it. Consider `auto j = factory(); auto k = j; // I need another one`